# Do December 2015 Fermilab Holometer experiment results suggest space-time not discretely emergent?

Tags: spacetime, holographic-principle

I read the December 2015 paper Search for Space-Time Correlations from the Planck Scale with the Fermilab Holometer [available here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01216) and looked at the various related posts here at PSE.

It seems to me that at least conceptually I could say, without invoking a particular novel model, that the results of the experiment made it appear less likely that locations in space-time are emerging as local collapses of wave functions subject to the expected uncertainty (since the transverse positional difference noise was not detected). In other words, we're not quite ready to say that space-time has ceased to exist (as Nima Arkani-Hamed put it in his paper, The Future of Fundamental Physics, 2012)?

Comment: If you are asking if the Holometer results mean anything, then the answer is that nobody knows but there are certainly a lot of opinions about it. Does it put Planck scale physics out of its misery? Probably not. That will require a Planck energy accelerator.

Comment: [According to Sabine Hossenfelder](http://backreaction.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/what-fermilabs-holometer-experiment.html) the holometer experiment has told us nothing useful.

Comment: I enjoyed reading Sabine's posts (on the holometer experiment and related). I'm surprised though that Fermilab's work here is considered meaningless. Going by their FAQ's at [link](http://holometer.fnal.gov/faq.html#how ) they precisely defined their attempt to observe very small jitter in transverse position to be expected if the uncertainty principle applied to space-time. Square root ofPlanck length * 40 meters seemed reasonably justified (as target movement). Would there be the same annoyance if the noise had materialized?